# Is it acceptable to use each byte of a PRNG-generated number separately?

Tags: random

Say you have a *non-cryptographically secure* [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) that generates 64-bit output.

Assuming that bytes are 8 bits, is it acceptable to use each byte of the 64-bit output as separate 8-bit random numbers or would that possibly break the randomness guarantees of a good PRNG? Or does it depend on the PRNG?

Because the PRNG is not cryptographically secure, the "randomness guarantee" I am worried about is not security, but whether the byte stream has the same guarantee of randomness, using the same definition of "randomness" that PRNG authors use, that the PRNG has with respect to its 64-bit output.

Comment: What "guarantees" are you talking about? If it is a good distribution that you seek, If you could statistically distinguish the bytes from random then you could statistically distinguish the numbers from random. If it is cryptographic security, if you could feasibly distinguish the bytes from random then you would be able to feasibly distinguish the numbers from random.

Comment: I forgot to say that I do not cryptographically secure guarantees. The guarantees I am referring to is that the stream still looks "random," for the definition of "random" that actual PRNG writers use. Will update question.

Comment: "Guarantee" is a strong word. If a generator does well with tests for randomness, and you get a byte generator out of it, does it do *equally* well? That is unlikely, in the sense that you would e.g. get different p-values. For a good generator, they should still be small. Surely this is a studied question.

Comment: @GavinHoward updated my answer, but basically: just run a Monte Carlo simulation on your PRNG and see if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite safe with a CSPRNG. For comparison it's like reading `/dev/random` byte by byte. With a good CSPRNG it is also perfectly acceptable to simply generate a 64bit sample 8 times and pick 8 bits per sample as well (throwing away the 56 other bits).

With PRNGs that are not CSPRNG you will have 'security' concerns in terms of the raw output of the PRNG that outweigh whether or not you chop up output into byte sized chunks.

In all cases it is vital to make sure the PRNG is seeded and periodically re-seeded correctly (so as to flush any possibly compromised internal state regularly). Security depends on the unpredictability of your internal state, which is ultimately driven by the quality of your seed input. One thing good CSPRNG implementations will do for you is to pessimistically estimate the amount of captured 'entropy' to safeguard the output from predictable internal state.

Note however that with 8 bits you only have 256 possible outputs in any case, so it becomes more of a question of how you *use* this. For instance, if you do something like XOR based encryption against the output of a PRNG (i.e. treating it as a one time pad based on some pre shared secret seed), then using a known plain text attack may relatively easily reveal the contents of the internal state of the PRNG. That is another type of attack which good CSPRNG implementations are supposed to guard against by their design (using e.g. a computationally secure hash function).

EDIT to add: if you don't care about 'security' but only need the output to look random, then this should be quite safe -- in theory a good PRNG is just as likely to yield a 0 as 1, and that should not vary between any octet. So you expect a linear distribution of possible output values. One thing you can do to verify whether this skews the distribution is to run a Monte Carlo simulation of some reasonably large size (e.g. 1M) and compare the histograms with 256 bins for both the raw 64 bit and the 8 * 8 bit output. You expect a roughly flat diagram for both cases if the linear distribution is preserved intact.

Comment: "in theory a good PRNG..." - In practice there are many not good PRNGs.  For instance, many C implementations continue to use totally garbage implementations of `rand()`.  "In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice.  In practice, there is."

Comment: @pjs certainly. Which is why the answer is: go forth and compare the histograms. For this question in particular the *absolute* quality of the PRNG does not matter as much as whether or not the proposed scheme of chopping up the native 64 bit output samples in 8bit sized chunks will skew distribution. Whether or not this effect is too pronounced due to PRNG biases can be tested for by comparing histograms of the outputs in both cases.

Comment: Histograms aren't sufficient.  A histogram would tell you that the two bit sequence "0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,..." is uniformly distributed, but it I doubt many of us would consider it acceptably random.  That's why test suites such as DieHarder check for sequential behaviors like runs of values above the mean vs below the mean, length of runs up or down, etc.  The sequential behavior is every bit as important as the aggregated behavior.

Comment: @pjs: that is quite true. In that vein it is worth noting that without re-seeding *all* PRNGs will eventually cycle (unless they are built to simply cease providing output, of course).

Comment: Actually, the bigger concern is what they're up to *before* they cycle.  For instance, you can fail a stream of 32 bit numbers with `p >= 0.99` after a mere 200,000 values if there are *no* duplicates -- the birthday paradox tells us that if the values really were independent you'd have seen at least one duplicate by that point.  Conversely, if you're using a modern generator with 128 bits or more of state space, cycling is not an issue since it won't occur within your lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the generator and its parameterization.  Quoting from the Wikipedia page for [Linear Congruential Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator): "The low-order bits of LCGs when m is a power of 2 should never be relied on for any degree of randomness whatsoever.  [...]any full-cycle LCG when m is a power of 2 will produce alternately odd and even results."